# Cannot set Kendo UI combobox selectedindex on creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I've created this combobox:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
            .Name("cropYear")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width: 75px;"})
            .Placeholder("something")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                  new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString(), Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString()   
                  },
                  new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), Value = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()   
                  },
                  new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString(), Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString()   
                  },
                  new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString(), Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year.ToString()   
                  },
                  new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year.ToString(), Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year.ToString()   
                  }
              })
              .SelectedIndex(2)
              .Suggest(true)
              .Events(
                events => events.Change("cropYearChanged")
              )
            .Height(200))
```

Even though I've set the SelectedIndex to 2, it's always 0.  When I try to change it in script like this:

```
$("#cropYear").data("kendoComboBox").select(1)
```

I get an error saying cannot call method 'select' of undefined

If I fire the change event, then I can access the combobox.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Is everything else working as expected or it is just that SelectedIndex(2) is not working ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you code. I copied and pasted it into my code editor. The SelectedIndex property correctly selected the index. Then I tried adding $("#cropYear").data("kendoComboBox").select(1), and it worked correctly also. You must have something else going on.

Comment: Yes, everything else is working as expected...and I can change the selected index, but only after the change event is fired.

Comment: what version of kendo is this?  you and Daniel are probably using different versions.